# Adding a product to the compare list redirects to the home page

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, compare

As stated, adding a product to the compare list redirects to the home page but I'd like it not to redirect at all. The product is successfully added to the list, the redirect is the only problem.

**Edit:** Same happens when "Clear"-ing the list. Interestingly enough, if you press "Clear" as a logged-in user at your dashboard, it correctly stays on the dashboard instead of redirecting to the homepage.

**Edit #2:** I figured it out, look below for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally fixed this problem, it was related to Magento adding .../index.php/... to everything after the base-url. The site worked but it looked weird so I removed it:

"On the **'Web'** page, navigate to **'Search Engine Optimisation'** tab and select **'YES'** underneath the **'Use Web Server Rewrites'** option."

and

"Now go to the root of your Magento website folder and use this code for your **.htaccess**:"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls) helped me fix the index.php issue and that fixed the redirection issue!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your server doesn't return the 'HTTP_REFERER' variable. This issue can be triggered by 3d party cache on the server or some of its settings.

I recommend you to check /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php and its addAction() method.

At the end of the method, there's a function called:

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

It leads to this function:

```
_getRefererUrl()
```

In the /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php file
check what this code returns:

```
$refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```

And let us know the result.

Comment: What's the best way to check what it returns?

Comment: Just enable logging under System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings 

and add this: 
Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'),null,'test.log'); to the code

Comment: Apparently I accidentally fixed it, it was because Magento was adding .../index.php/... to everything and an hour or two ago I read up on how to prohibit that. Thanks for the help!